# Using remote images with gatsby-image

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I've got a series of promos on my Gatsby site that are pulling their data from a database using `gatsby-source-mysql`. Within this data, I have a node for images called `ad_filename` which, for example, returns `ad_image_1.jpg`. I've got the full asset URL set as an environmental variable, but since I'm only getting the filename in my `graphql` queries, I'm not able to use the plugin's built in `remoteImageFieldNames` and make the images work with `gatsby-image.` That being said,  I'd like to so I can control dimensions/optimization etc. Is there a way to convert relative, remote paths to usable nodes?

This is my config for `gatsby-source-mysql`:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mysql`,
      options: {
        connectionDetails: {
          host: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_HOST,
          user: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_USER,
          database: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_NAME,
          password: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        },
        queries: [
          {
            statement: 'SELECT * FROM crm_dealers where state != ""',
            idFieldName: 'subdomain',
            name: 'Dealers',
          },
          {
            statement:
              'SELECT lm.*, d.subdomain domain FROM crm_lp_mgmt lm INNER JOIN crm_dealers d ON d.id = lm.dealer_id WHERE lm.ad_title != ""',
            idFieldName: 'id',
            name: 'Promos',
            parentName: 'Dealers',
            foreignKey: 'subdomain',
            cardinality: 'OneToMany',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

This is my query for the promos:

```
query Promos($subdomain: StringQueryOperatorInput = {}){
  allMysqlPromos(filter: { subdomain: $subdomain }) {
    edges {
      node {
        ad_filename
        ad_title
        ad_body
        URL_ext
        subdomain
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what the query is returning:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMysqlPromos": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "ad_filename": "ad_002910.jpg",
            "ad_title": "Buy One, Get One Free",
            "ad_body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis quam venenatis porta sed. Aliquet eget lobortis quam ut dignissim eget quam lobortis. Elementum, at nullam tincidunt viverra pulvinar ac porta sed mauris. Sit leo imperdiet turpis morbi arcu, posuere odio sit.",
            "URL_ext": "/promo-jesse",
            "subdomain": "sacramento"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "ad_filename": "ad_002911.jpg",
            "ad_title": "Buy Two, Get Four Free",
            "ad_body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis quam venenatis porta sed. Aliquet eget lobortis quam ut dignissim eget quam lobortis. Elementum, at nullam tincidunt viverra pulvinar ac porta sed mauris. Sit leo imperdiet turpis morbi arcu, posuere odio sit.",
            "URL_ext": "promo-jesse-two",
            "subdomain": "sacramento"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, to clarify again, I make sure that the results of `ad_filename` are converted into nodes that I can run through `childImageSharp` for optimization etc. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables should store sensitive data, such as your `host`, `user`, `database`, or `password`, as you are doing. Store images URLs in that files is the main purpose of the file, moreover, having a MySQL database to store that information.

I would strongly suggest storing this kind of data in your database.

[According to the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-mysql/#download-image-for-image-processing), you can use `gatsby-image` from a remote image using the URL as a parameter:

> If your queries stores the remote url for image and you would like to
> utilize image processing of Gatsby, provide `remoteImageFieldNames` to
> the query object.
>
> > Make sure you’ve installed both [`gatsby-plugin-sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sharp/) and
> > [`gatsby-transform-sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-sharp/) packages and add them to your `gatsby-config.js`.
>
> For example, assuming you have a actor table where the profile_url
> column stores the remote image url, e.g.
> `'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/10/11/15/balloons-388973_1280.jpg'`.

In your case:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mysql`,
      options: {
        connectionDetails: {
          host: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_HOST,
          user: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_USER,
          database: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_NAME,
          password: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        },
        queries: [
          {
            statement: 'SELECT * FROM crm_dealers where state != ""',
            idFieldName: 'subdomain',
            name: 'Dealers',
          },
          {
            statement:
              'SELECT lm.*, d.subdomain domain FROM crm_lp_mgmt lm INNER JOIN crm_dealers d ON d.id = lm.dealer_id WHERE lm.ad_title != ""',
            idFieldName: 'id',
            name: 'Promos',
            parentName: 'Dealers',
            foreignKey: 'subdomain',
            cardinality: 'OneToMany',
            remoteImageFieldNames: ['ad_filename']
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

*Note: notice the `remoteImageFieldNames: ['ad_filename']`.*

`remoteImageFieldNames` field is a column that contains an image URL that you want to download and utilize Gatsby's image processing capability.

That's it, Gatsby, using transformers and sharps will create a queryable node for that image where you will be able to add to your `gatsby-image.`

If you don't/not able to use the built-in method. You can still tell Gatsby that you have an image to be parsed locally by using [Gatsby's filesystem](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/):

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: `${__dirname}/your/path/to/images/`,
  },
},
```

*Note: of course, you can have multiple instances of `gatsby-source-filesystem`.*

Gatsby will look into that directory and will parse what's inside (images in this case), creating the corresponding node for each image. You just need to query it with:

```
{
  allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        extension
        dir
        modifiedTime
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`sourceInstanceName` stands for the `name` in the `gatsby-source-filesystem` options. Add as many filters as needed to get your desired image.

Comment: Yes, the problem that I’m having is my `ad_filename` doesn’t return the full url of the image, only the file name. They’re stored on a remote Cloudways server from our internal CRM, and it’s only returning the name of the file. Using `remoteImageFieldNames` fails, saying that the field is not a url, hence my problems.

Comment: Can you manipulate your database? If the images are stored locally, having the name you can filter a query via context yo get that image.